# D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException Retrofit2 +RxJava2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm trying to learn how Retrofit+RxJava work and I'm testing some example. If I call a List of objects I can print on console this list of objects. Here below the code:

```
Disposable disposable = apiInterface.getArea("4744", ".")
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Area>>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onNext(List<Area> areas) {
                                       Log.d("Response"," Value Area "+areas);
                                   }

                                   @Override
                                   public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                       Log.d("Error","JSON Error "+ e.getMessage());
                                   }

                                   @Override
                                   public void onComplete() {

                                   }
                               }
                );
```

Model class:

```
public class Area {

    @SerializedName("v_area")
    private String typeArea;

    @SerializedName("area")
    private String desArea;


    public Area(String typeArea, String desArea) {
        this.typeArea = typeArea;
        this.desArea = desArea;
    }

    public String getTypeArea() {
        return typeArea;
    }

    public void setTypeArea(String typeArea) {
        this.typeArea = typeArea;
    }

    public String getDesArea() {
        return desArea;
    }

    public void setDesArea(String desArea) {
        this.desArea = desArea;
    }

}
```

Whereas if I try to receive a list of objects and convert in a list of strings with RxJava operators I get the error:"D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

```
Disposable disposable = apiInterface.getArea("4744",".")
                .map(response -> Observable.fromIterable(response))
                .flatMap(x->x)
                .map(Area::getTypeArea)
                .toList()
                .toObservable()
                .subscribe(this::handlerResponse,this::handlerError);


    }

    private void handlerResponse(List<String> strings) {
        System.out.println(strings);
    }

    private void handlerError(Throwable throwable) {
        Log.d("Error ","Response Error "+throwable.getMessage());
    }
```

Can anyone help me to solve?
One more question please...Can I have an example to catch response error? Because I no receive any http status error, but only a null on console.

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException. Please tell what it means.

Comment: I set in AndroidManifest.xml <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>. First call works fine, but not the second call. When I run the app on the console I get the HTTP FAILED: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. I can't understand where the problem is

Comment: What does it mean: Network on Main thread?

Comment: I understood your question..Thanks for your help. I forgot .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

Comment: Please could you give me some code example how to manage the error response message?

Comment: What does it mean if somebody tells you that you are executing network code on the main thread? And doing so is forbidden. And if you do you get a NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: In your failing example, why didn't you apply `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`?

Comment: Because I forgot them. Now I can convert Observable object in a List or in  a Map. Yesterday I asked some example of error response message. Could you give me some example to manage http status error? . I'm testing Retrofit + RxJava because I don' t know well them and because I need to modify some app wrote with Volley.